# What populate ViewData["content"] or ViewData["Header"]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have encountered a piece of code that I don't understand. We are looping through a ViewData["Content"] using foreach, but I can't see where it's being populated from. The question arise as we are getting an error in production but when I try to debug locally it works OK. I checked in the application and ViewData["Content"] isn't being set anywhere 
I have something like

```
foreach (var contentType in (List<AppCode.ContentType>)ViewData["Content"]){ ....}
```

Can anyone shade any light?

I was expecting to see something like 
`ViewData[“content”] ="blablaba"` or `ViewData[“Header”]="lalalal"` but I can't see it anywhere in the application.

Comment: ViewData is used to pass information between a controller and a view. It would have to be getting its values from some execution path of the `ActionMethod` on a controller that is returning your view.  Without any more code from you, it is impossible dig in any further than that.

Comment: Thanks, But's why I asked the question, Basically there is no where ViewData["Content"] is set. Like ViewData["Content"] = "blablabla". So i was wondering if ViewData[“content”] or ViewData[“Header”] is an MVC kind of property

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in the default MVC implementation that sets ViewData.  If it's getting set, it must be coming from someplace in your code, or from some 3rd-party library you are using.  Either way, we can't see your code, so we can't really be much help.

Comment: Thanks that's OK. just out of the blue, does adding something to the current context add it in the viewdata?

Answer (score 0):

As [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewdata?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2), **ViewData** is a dictionary that contains data to pass between the controller and the view.

This is mostly set in the `Controller` methods like this:

```
ViewBag.Content = "some text";
```

or like this:

```
ViewData["Content"] = "some text";
```

*ViewData* and *ViewBag* are used for the same purpose -- to transfer data from controller to view. *ViewData* is nothing but a dictionary of objects and it is accessible by string as key. They are used to access the same values from **Controller -> View -> PartialView**

Both are part of `ViewPage` class.

So depending on other parts of your code you should look for a *controller method that is used to render your view*, or the *view that renders a partial* as the ViewBag and ViewData can be passed as parameters.

Comment: I know but that's why I am asking I can't find anywhere where this is being set

Comment: Well, without the code that sets the values, there are no default values in ViewData, so there must be some setter in the code. Without further information it is hard to tell more

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is a [ViewData] attribute on some "Content" or "Header" Property somewhere.  This is available from ASP.Net Core 2.1.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [ViewData]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        Title = "About Us";
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2